# set default font size for \caption*{}

Tags: captions, fontsize

I currently use `\caption*{}` elements from the `caption` package to add small notes and explanations underneath figures and tables. Since I want those notes to be small I write them as

```
\caption*{\footnotesize This is a note}
```

I have a **lot** of these so setting the `\footnotesize` every time seems a tad redundant. Is there any way to set a default font size for the `\caption*{}` element and for that element alone (in particular: to leave `\caption{}` unaffected)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new command that way:

```
\newcommand\mynote[1]{\footnotesize#1}
```

A better solution, in my opinion, would be to load the `threeparttable` package and write in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\footnotesize}
```

Then use the environment as follows:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{xxx}
............
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[] Note/explanation1
\item[] Note/explanation2
..........................
\end{tablenotes}
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

The notes will have the width of the table. For figures, the corresponding environment is `measuredfigure`.

For long tables, you'll use the `threeparttablex` package. The syntax is slightly different: the environment is  now `ThreePartTable` and the `TableNotes` environment is written at the beginning of the environment; the notes are inserted anywhere you want with the `\inserTableNotes` command, and they can be referenced. Finally, you have a `\setTableNoteFont` command.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the `\caption*`command if you only need some notes. Simply do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\def\Par{\par\footnotesize}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
foo\Par
this is some nonsense text
\end{table}

\begin{table}\centering
foo
\caption{this is some nonsense text}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```